# cocoa objective-c NSDictionary with integer objects

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

Why does `dict2` show a warning about its object not being a pointer when `dict1` shows no such warning?

Shouldn't both show this warning? both are integers..

erg.

```
NSDictionary *dict1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:0 forKey:TAG_KEY];
NSDictionary *dict2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:1 forKey:TAG_KEY];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously, ints are not objects — but 0 in a pointer context is interpreted as nil/NULL. In fact, that's precisely how nil is defined. From objc.h:

```
#define Nil 0           /* id of Nil class */
#define nil 0           /* id of Nil instance */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use class `NSNumber` if you want integers in the dictionary.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question sir!

Comment: @binnyb: the question as posed was adequately answered by Chuck. I'm merely pointing out that what you're doing is VERY WRONG - integers don't belong in NSDictionary. NSDictionary will try to do object things to them - retain/release, for example. Which will cause a lot of grief. There's a workaround, however - integers can be wrapped in an object type called NSNumber.